# Basically it states that Choice Is Not Defined

Tags: python

```
pin1 = int(input("Please set a pin: "))
print("Welcome to Satan's Soul Bank, Enter ya pin!")
attempt = int(input("Please enter your pin number first"))
if attempt == pin1:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Deposit Souls")
    print("2.Withdraw Souls")
    print("3.Check Soul balance")
    choice = int(input("Enter choice(1/2/3): "))
if choice == 1:
    Deposit = int(input("How many Souls would you like to deposit?: "))
    print ('You now have' , Deposit + 1042, 'Souls')
if choice == 2:
    Withdraw = int(input("How many Souls would you like to withdraw?: "))
if Withdraw < 1042:
     print ('You have withdrawn' , Withdraw, 'Souls, and now have' , Withdraw -1042, 'Souls left')
if Withdraw > 1042:
     print ('You do not have enough souls in your account to Withdraw that much')
elif choice == 3:
    print ("You have 1042 souls in your bank account")
elif attempt != pin1:
            for i in range(2):
                    attempt = int(input("Invalid Attempt Please enter your pin number again"))
            print ("Card Swallowed Contact SATAN")
```

Whenever I try running the code it states that choice is not defined, the Code is basically meant to swallow the card if the user gets the pin wrong 3 times however it stops stating that Choice is not defined and if the User does get it right it still says that Choice is not defined, am I missing some extra code and if so were or is the way it is formatted?

Comment: Yes, because what is happening is that your code does not enter the first condition whenever the input is not equal to `pin1`, which is where you first introduce `choice`. Instead, what you should do is initialize this `choice` before your conditional statements. Something like `choice = 0`.

Comment: Mind putting it in code to show me?

Comment: Ok and whilst you are here could you also proof check the code and help me make amendments after fixing the code thanks to your code I face trouble with the if it is this specifically the Withdraw part

Comment: With the correction I provided, that resolves the issue you asked about. I suggest you go back to your code and follow it carefully to see what else is not working. If you are still having trouble with other things, then make sure you carefully read how to put together a [mcve] and post a new question clearly explaining what new problems you are having. But make sure that you read the link I provided in order for your question to be well received by readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a small sample of your code, you simply need to do something like this:

```
pin1 = int(input("Please set a pin: "))
print("Welcome to Satan's Soul Bank, Enter ya pin!")
attempt = int(input("Please enter your pin number first"))
choice = 0
if attempt == pin1:
    # rest of your code here
```

As you can see, by putting the `choice` variable before any of your conditional statements, assures that it is created and will hold a default value. This helps solve *this* particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

The *choice* variable is only being defined if the *PIN* matches.

When the *PIN* doesn't match, there needs to be an else-clause that stops the code from running further into the secured part of the code:

```
pin1 = int(input("Please set a pin: "))
print("Welcome to Satan's Soul Bank, Enter ya pin!")
attempt = int(input("Please enter your pin number first"))
if attempt == pin1:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Deposit Souls")
    print("2.Withdraw Souls")
    print("3.Check Soul balance")
else:
    print("The PIN did not match.  Exiting")
    raise RuntimeError('Security:  PIN did not match')
```

The last three lines are new.